# How to set access control on the hdfs that results from installing the hadoop plugin for hudson

Tags: hudson, hadoop

I installed the hudson plugin that enables hadoop. Now I find that I don't have access as myself to put any data in there. It's not at all obvious to me how hudson has configured hadoop. Can someone tell me how to change these permisisons?

Answer (score 2):

The hudson configuration for hadoop can be found in

```
$HUDSON_HOME/hadoop/dist/conf
```

Details on configuration of [hadoop](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop) (down the page a bit to the configuration files section).

Comment: I changed the dfs supergroup in there, restarted, and it had no effect. Are you sure that those options are live, and that this just isn't the unpack? The source code of the plugin seems to establish its own options programmatically.

Comment: @bmargulies - It looks as though the plugin should override a few settings to create a hardoop cluster that matches your hudson topology. On the plugin page it looks as though v1.1 was supposed to explicitly expose hadoop-site.xml and hadoop-default.xml... Hrmm, just tried to have a bit of a tinker on a windows box. I couldn't even get the plugin to load cleanly: What does the HDFS status give you in the hadoop link on hudson?

Comment: Clinton, if you can file that as a bug in http://issues.hudson-ci.org/ that would be greatly appreciated.